# which is right place to open/close database resources in list fragment with Async Task loader

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite, android-loadermanager

Which is the best place to open and close Database resources in ListFragment which implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks?

I have a list fragment which implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`. Now I init loader in `onActivityCreated` and in `onCreateLoader` returned a Loader(MyLoader). The MyLoader class open database resources.then Cursor object returned to  `onLoadFinished`. Here where can i close my opened databse,because we cannot close database before cursor returnted to onLoadFinished.

Many persons said, open database resources in Activity onResume and close in onPause is best.But if i use AsynctaskLoaders how to close the database resources?

I got following error,

```
close() was never explicitly called on database 'mydb' 
android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1849)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `close` the `Cursor` after you completed ur operations on Database. Try to make use of common `SQLiteOpenHelper`(have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)) for all the Activities instead of calling Database open/close in every `Activity`.

Comment: yes i already have SqliteOpenHelper Class common for all activity.I have loader class which extends simplecursorLoader. In the loader class i intialized like,DBHelper myDbHelper=new DBHelper(context);
SQLiteDatabase myDB = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); This loader class returns cursor object. Then where i close the myDbHelper and myDB.